# What is this wierd thang in the back of my van?

Tags: ford, part-identification, econoline

I was spendin' the day fixin some stupid door latches on this van.  Newly acquired 5.4 v8 1998 e150 Ford.  She needs love.

I fixed the latches Mcgyver style... thought I was gonna need dynamite but turned out all a needed was some sewing scissors and periscope.

but, anyhow... I come across this wierd kinda goofy lil' thang in the back.  Made think, "WHAT IN THE HEYL?!?!?"

Here, take a gander:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now I am head scratchin'

What in the heyl is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like the clamp or safety clamp for the spare wheel carrier.

You might find it useful to search for an owners manual for the car online or second-hand as that will help you with many things you don't yet know about the car.

This video shows how to use it - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ywj5W_YhHUk

Comment: @HandyHowie Thanks for the edit and useful addition.